# Kubuntu 23.04 / 6.2.0-33-generic kernel: Blank screen w mouse and that’s it

Tags: boot, kubuntu, freeze, 23.04

When I boot up, I hit esc to get the console messages. I see smart and cups start, then I get where Plymouth boot and console setvtrgb.service finished. Then a mouse pointer that I can move appears and that’s it. Not using an NVIDIA gpu (Intel620). Help please?